# Through-hole wire-wound resistor footprint in EAGLE

Tags: resistors, eaglecad

I think the EAGLE component search algorithm is stupidly written because whenever I try to search for a specific component it won't show up, then I have to manually search each one in its own category and it's really annoying.

I am trying to find the footprint for the **through-hole wire-wound** resistor. I have found that [resistor-power.lbr](https://www.diymodules.org/eagle-show-library?type=std&file=resistor-power.lbr) contains those footprints but I couldn't find it in my library.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way to search in eagle is to use the * character. For example `"LM*"` will bring up all parts staring with LM and `"*LM*"` will bring up all parts containg LM.

Although eagle, like every other circuit design tool does not have everything. Designing your own parts can be an essential tool. (Albeit a pain in the a**)

Answer (score 1):

I have been using eagle for a while now and I used to face the same problems in the beginning. Searching for the exact package that you are using might be a tedious process and since the package has been made by someone else, you must verify whether the package is exactly same as what you are using or not by taking a print-out of your board file. (I have wasted my time and money because I relied on someone else's work. You don't need to.)

The best way out seems to be making your own package and a library. I have made my own personal library and even if the part is commonly available in other libraries, I just copy them in mine. This way, I have an organized library of the parts that I am using and I can be sure that these packages will work every time.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't quickly find a suitable footprint in the library, make your own (and save it in your own library).

This applies to *any* CAD system - Eagle, Altium, KiCAD, or whatever.